# Multiple open id connect ad providers in a CMS setup

Tags: azure-active-directory, owin, openid-connect, episerver, .net-4.7.2

**The case**

Currently trying to setup two AD providers (both on OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol).

One would need to handle users for the back office and the other should be used in all other cases to login external users with different roles. Content on the website is only accessible for certain roles.

**The setup**

- EPiServer (CMS)
- .Net 4.7.2 framework

**Important notes:**

- Both open id connect middlewares are currently set to authentication mode 'active' .

**Status**

Both AD providers can be challenged directly where the right login portal shows, however there are some problems i cannot explain. Working with two open id connect middelwares is a first for me.

**Problem 1**

In a CMS setup certain location/paths are defined in the web.config like the following

```
<location path="episerver">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="WebEditors, WebAdmins, Administrators" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

When the '/episerver' path is hit it triggers an authentication flow. If one middleware has been marked to run in the pipeline stage 'authentication' that middleware seems to always handle such requests, however if both middleware are registered to run in same pipeline stage 'authentication' the last registered middleware (in the owin startup file) always seems to handle all requests. Why is that ?

**Problem 2**

When the first middleware is registered to run for the authentication pipeline stage, and the second is registered to run for a later pipeline stage (the default seems to be 'PreRequestHandlerExecute' when its not specified) another strange behaviour happens.

When any controller that has a '[Authorize]' attribute assigned is hit with a request, my guess would be the first middleware would be challenged because it is the first 'active' middleware defined in the Owin pipeline, however it is the second middleware that is hit. I can't find any explaination on this strange behaviour ?

Comment: Are you using something like AzureAD for backend and IdentityServer/Auth0 for the frontend? I'd typically say that multiple OpenID-providers is a bad pattern, how will you allo editors to edit content on the non-backend parts? I would typically implement a trust to the other openid-providers in the one that can be used by all. E.g. setup IdentityServer and add your asp.net identity, add other OpenID-providers to the config like AzureAD, Facebook, Google etc.

Comment: I am using both AzureAD and Azure B2C AD for the backend. The first handles authetication requests triggered by the path “/episerver” which will enable editors to login to the CMS back office. The other (B2C) handles all other request use cases at the moment such as the scenario described in my problem 2. 

Most documentation for Owin just suggest it’s possible for more than one middleware to be registered so i assumed i was on the right path. I will try your suggestion about trusting the other provided i Think i have seen this in azure. The result would be only one middleware Right ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure the back-office azure ad config to only trigger on /episerver and the regular users on everything else in startup.cs

Both can use the same cookie auth setup but will need 2 instances of OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions, one for each azure ad.

So you can do like this:

```
app.MapWhen(!ctx.Request.Path.StartsWith("/episerver"), cmsApp => 
{
  cmsApp.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(cmsOptions);
}
app.Map("/episerver", editorApp => 
{
  editorApp.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(editorOptions);
}
```

Comment: I actually have 2 instances of UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and 2 instances of UseCookieAuthentication. 1 for each. 

The result is 2 different named cookies, with different authentication types. 

My understanding was i needed unique authentication types in order to challenge them directly. (Account/login controller).

Comment: 1 middleware already seems to handle the back office URL “/episerver” due to what is defined in my web.config (see problem 1). I wonder what would happen if i map Them instead as you suggest.